# The background picture don't shows up

Tags: html, background-image

I tried all possible answers but nothing works. When I put this code
I have a gray screen only. The picture is in the same folder which I use for code. I use notepad. I am a beginner.

I've tried all your answers but nothing works only gray screen. The image works when I put just `src=(image.png)` but not working if I want a background with `URL(image.png)`

Comment: Welcome to SO @pitrus1957 It is always better to include the relevent code in question...

Comment: <html>
<title>
Piotr@Ewa World
</title>
<head>
<style>
body{background :url("IMG_20180505_204226.png");
}
</style>
</head>
</html>

Comment: This is because you don't have body tag...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `body` tag, like so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Piotr@Ewa World </title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: url("IMG_20180505_204226.png");
      background-size: contain; /* Or "cover" */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works very well. God bless you